# Details Related to One-variable Calculus in a proof of Morse Lemma.

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, morse-theory

I'm reading M. Audin and M. Damian's book $\textit{Morse Theory and Floer Homology}$ and i'm having an issue on a proposition that is "Morse Lemma" [here](https://books.google.co.id/books?id=WIq4BAAAQBAJ&pg=PA585&lpg=PA585&dq=morse+theory+audin&source=bl&ots=pLol_XWvSx&sig=ACfU3U3mEP0frr2oC2lvRkwsWjGsyxjG0w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwillMeOuK7nAhVX63MBHfokDhMQ6AEwCXoECA0QAQ#v=onepage&q=morse%20lemma&f=false) page 13. This proof about Morse Lemma is a little bit different compared to the standard proof as in Milnor's and most books. So i can't find out wheather this is a typo or not by looking at another book.

As i understand, it's only about the one variable calculus part that i got confused (what a poor student). The argument is as follows

In page 13 we have an expression 
$$
f(x) = f(0) + \frac{1}{2}f''(0) \, x^2 + \varepsilon(x) \, x^2. 
$$
Without much explanation in the book i assume that, the expression above is the Taylor's expansion with the remainder terms wrote as integral representation, where the linear term $f'(0)\,x$ is vanish since we're assuming $0$ is a critical point. So i assuming that above expression is appear as follows
\begin{align}
f(x) &= f(0) + \frac{1}{2}f''(0) \, x^2 + \frac{1}{2} \int_0^{x} f'''(t)(x-t)^2 dt\\
&= f(0) + \frac{1}{2}f''(0) \, x^2 + x^2 \Big(\frac{1}{2x^2} \int_0^{x} f'''(t)(x-t)^2 dt \Big) \\
&= f(0) + \frac{1}{2}f''(0) \, x^2 + x^2 \varepsilon(x).
\end{align}
So $\varepsilon(x)$ must be $\frac{1}{2x^2} \int_0^{x} f'''(t)(x-t)^2 dt $. But then why in a sentence after that expression in the book, it says that 
$$
\varepsilon(x) = \frac{1}{2} \int_0^{x} f'''(t)(x-t)^2 dt \quad ?
$$
I'm really sorry for wasting your time if this is a silly question and it's just my ignorance. Would anyone help me with this one ? Thank you.

Comment: Looks like a typo. Is that formula used later in the book?

Comment: @robjohn Maybe. I don't think it is used anywhere. Only in that proposition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I somehow managed to contact one of the authors and it turns out that it is a typo. The fixed argument runs as follows : By Taylor-Young expansion around a neighbourhood of $0$ we have

\begin{align}
f(x) &= f(0) + \frac{1}{2}f''(0) \, x^2 + o(x^2) \\
     &= f(0) + \frac{1}{2}f''(0) \, x^2 + x^2 \varepsilon(x), \quad \varepsilon(x) = o(x^2)/x^2 \\
&= f(0) \pm  \frac{1}{2}|f''(0)| \, (1+\varepsilon(x)) \cdot  x^2,
\end{align}

and then define $\tilde{x} = \varphi(x):= x\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}|f''(0)| (1+\varepsilon(x))}$ and note that this indeed local diffeomorphism since $\varphi'(0)=\sqrt{|f''(0)|/2} \neq 0$ by nondegeneracy.